# How do I use JavaScript to produce a distinct output of all combinations of values from an array?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm new to coding so please help me in writing this code in javascript.

I have this array:

```
var Arr = [1,2,3];
```

I want it to produce the following output:

```
1-1
1-2 
1-3 
2-2 
2-3 
3-3
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
for(a = 1; a <= arr.length; a++){
  for(b = 1; b <= arr.length; b++){
    if(a <= b)
      console.log(a + "-" + b)
  }
}
```

Comment: Neither your answer and nor your way of answering is good! Learn the persons dont feed them...

Comment: He didn't mentioned dynamic case. I guess

Answer (score -1):

```
var Arr = [1,2,3];
var result = [];
Arr.forEach(function(item, index){
  for(var i = index; i<= Arr.length - 1; i++){
    if(index<=i){
      result.push(item + '-' + Arr[i]);
    }
}});
```

Comment: this is not requirement

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.